# How to output html with variables

Tags: php, parsing

I am learning to build a whole simple website in PHP, but some of the code has an error. I have partially fixed it and I am hoping to learn from fixing the error on the older code which is PHP 5+.

The original offending code was this, the echo line, just one line, which cause a parsing error on firefox

```
<?php
        foreach ($navItems as $item) {
            echo "<li><a href=\"$item['slug']\">$item['title']</a></li>";
        }
    ?>
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

I tried to improve it with this

```
<?php
    foreach ($navItems as $item) {
        echo '<li><a href="$item' . '["slug"]">$item["title"]</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

But now it 'echo' out incorrectly with - $item["title"] - for each menu item

If the correction I made is correct then I will have to drop the course as it will be too difficult to correct all, if you can help with this small problem i would be very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to use concatenation in php.

```
echo "<li><a href=\\".$item['slug']."\\>".$item['title']."</a></li>";
```

I'll suggest looking into string interpolation as it is much faster.

Here is how to use string interpolation in php. Read more [here](https://phpbench.com/)

```
echo "<li><a href=\\{$item['slug']}\\>{$item['title']}</a></li>";
```

Comment: I will follow up on this. Very useful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `'` and `"` marks have different behaviours.

Try this it, is easier for beginners:

```
<?php
    foreach ($navItems as $item) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . $item['slug'] . '">' . $item['title'] .'</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly - Thank you

Comment: Actually this one carried the " symbol into the echo output

Comment: You would want the " symbol for correct html formatting. I just updated my answer. Is this how you want it?

Comment: I used this one for now as it works. Thanks for your help
echo "<li><a href=\\".$item['slug']."\\>".$item['title']."</a></li>";

Comment: Ok. With html, you want the href in quotes. So `<a href=//example.com>test</a>` may cause issues with some browser, but `<a href="//example.com">test</a>` is more valid.